# swift function definition syntax

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to understand what 'didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo' means in the following swift function definition.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
}
```

I see that 'info' means dictionary collection type, but I don't get why it is preceded with 'didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo'.
I am new to swift and iOS development in general please help to answer probably trivial question.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234):

> Modifying External Parameter Name Behavior for Methods
>
> Sometimes it’s useful to provide an external parameter name for a
>   method’s first parameter, even though this is not the default
>   behavior. To do so, you can add an explicit external name yourself.
>
> Conversely, if you do not want to provide an external name for the
>   second or subsequent parameter of a method, override the default
>   behavior by using an underscore character (_) as an explicit external
>   parameter name for that parameter.

This means that in your method, the word `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is the variable name used when calling the method. However, you get the data from that in the `info` variable. For example, in your case, the method would be called as `imagePickerController(picker: <UIImagePickerController>, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: <info>)`, because the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` substitutes the `info`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah thanks. This is a bit weird why this structure exists - I guess it makes function calls more readable.

Comment: @IevgeniiFedorenko Yeah, there's a lot of things in Swift like this that don't make sense initially, such as the `if let` statement, but once you get used to them, they're quite handy. I highly suggest reading through the [Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) book. It's quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to give parameters sort of an alias to the more verbose version. So instead of using `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` as a variable to manipulate, you will only have to use the local parameter (or alias) called `info`.

> Specifying External Parameter Names
>
> You write an external parameter name before the local parameter name
>   it supports, separated by a space:
>
> ```
> func someFunction(externalParameterName localParameterName: Int) {
>     // function body goes here, and can use localParameterName
>     // to refer to the argument value for that parameter
> }
> ```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID167